# Backbone click event: Trigger only on element actually clicked on

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, mouseclick-event

In a Backbone application, I instantiate a view for every model in a collection.

If one of these views is clicked, I want to call a function.

Unfortunately, the function is called *n* times, where *n* is the number of models/view instantiated. I’ve managed to get around this by finding out what element has been clicked on, but I still don’t feel comfortable knowing that one event might be triggered 200+ times in the very same moment.

The event is bound like this:

```
var Item = Backbone.View.extend({
    events: {
        'click .list-group-item': function(event) { this.doSomething(event); },
    },

    doSomething: function(event) {
        $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('active');
    },
});
```

In the code above you can also see my workaround using `event.currentTarget`, but how can I avoid this? Is there a way to distinguish the `.list-group-item` elements without resorting to `event.currentTarget`, so preferable right in the moment an element is clicked?

Another approach would be to bind the event to the parent element, so it is only triggered once and then using `event.currentTarget`, but that also seems kind of fishy to me.

Comment: Why are you actually invoking the function in the events hash, instead of just registering it?  If you do this: `'click .list-group-item': 'doSomething',`, it won't actually run the function until the individual element is clicked.  (The `event` object is automatically passed in)

Comment: @dwenzel because otherwise, the event won't fire for some reason. But I didn't knew that the `event` is passed in by default, thanks for that info!

Comment: What is this view's element?  Is it the '.list-group-item' itself?  If so, you may need to do this: `'click': 'doSomething'`.
To test, I would put a debugger as the first line of the doSomething function definition.  Then, see if you enter the function when you click, and play around with `event` in the console.

Comment: @dwenzel Now it works, it was just me being stupid, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to attach to a click anywhere in the view, you don't need to specify `.list-group-item`. Also, you only need to specify the name of the event callback function:

```
var Item = Backbone.View.extend({
  events: {
    'click': 'doSomething'
  },

  doSomething: function(event) {
    $(event.currentTarget).toggleClass('active');
  },
});
```